# How to pass a form input value into a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a generic JavaScript function which takes one parameter

```
function foo(val) { ...}
```

and I want to call the function when submit a form

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="formValueId"/>
<input type="button" onclick="foo(this.formValueId)"/>
</form>
```

but the expression foo(this.formValueId) does not work (not surprised, it was a desperate attempt), So the question is, how can I pass a form value to the javascript function. 
As I mentioned the javascript is generic and I don't want to manipulate the form inside it!

I could create a helper function in the middle to get the form values with jQuery (for example) and then call the function but I was wondering if I can do it without the helper function.

Comment: This may be your answer. demo: http://jsbin.com/icikav/5/edit#javascript,html The method you're trying to call isn't defined.

Comment: Be advised that it is possible to submit this form by hitting Enter in the text field (not in IE though) and your button click will not be triggered.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It might be cleaner to take out your inline click handler and do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button-id').click(function() {
      foo($('#formValueId').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 19):

Give your inputs names it will make it easier

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
<input type="button" onclick="foo(this.form.valueId.value)"/>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you give your button an id things can be even easier:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
<input type="button" id="theButton"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("theButton"),
value =  button.form.valueId.value;
button.onclick = function() {
    foo(value);
}
```

Comment: instead of     `onclick="foo(this.form.valueId.value)"`  we can use 
    `onclick="foo(valueId.value)"`. it works...

Answer (score 6):

Use `onclick="foo(document.getElementById('formValueId').value)"`

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to approach this. Personally, I would [avoid in-line scripting](http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript-). Since you've tagged jQuery, let's use that.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
      foo($('#formValueId').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well ya you can do that in this way.

```
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="showAddress(address.value)" value="ShowMap"/>
```

Java Script

```
function showAddress(address){

    alert("This is address :"+address)

}
```

That is one example for the same. and that will run.

Comment: please add the java script also

Answer (score 1):

More stable approach:

```
<form onsubmit="foo($("#formValueId").val());return false;">
<input type="text" id="formValueId"/>
<input type="submit" value="Text on the button"/>
</form>
```

The `return false;` is to prevent actual form submit (assuming you want that).