# Passing form value to javascript url

Tags: java, php, forms, post

I have a form that will collect input from the user and it consist of a button. Once a user click on the button, a pop up message will be shown.

I would like to post the form inputs to the url stated in the javascript.

```
<div class="live-preview">
     <a class="confirm" id="alert">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-common uppercase" value="Edit Booking">
     </a>
     <script>
     $(".confirm").easyedit();
     $("#alert").click(function() {
           window.location = "processEditBookSeat.php";
     });
     </script>
     <input name="workshopSeatLeft" type="hidden" id="workshopSeatLeft" value="<?php echo $resultWorkshopDetail['workshopDetailSeatLeft']?>">
     <input name="alreadyBookedSeat" type="hidden" id="alreadyBookedSeat" value="<?php echo $userBookedSeat?>">
     <input name="workshopID" type="hidden" id="workshopID" value="<?php echo $getWorkshopID?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to pass the parameters? In the path, the query part or the fragment part? Can you provide an expected URL?

Comment: I want to pass it to processEditBookSeat.php under confirming the alert box

Comment: Meaning something like this : `processEditBookSeat.php?workshopID=1234&alreadyBookedSeat=false&workshopSeatLeft=true` ?

Comment: This will result to GET. Is there a way to POST?

Comment: Yes there is a jQuery post method, takes as argument the URL, a plain object (name, value) and some callbacks for the state (on success on error ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716848/how-to-pass-a-form-input-value-into-a-javascript-function

Comment: @ravindra the question is similar but here is asked how to post the params. I don't think is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `submit` the form using post to a specific adress and therefor direct to this address use

```
$('#form').attr('action', "/yoururl").submit();
```

If however you want to post it in the background use

```
$.post(url, $('#form').serialize());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either create an Ajax request and on success to redirect the page or you can submit a form as in the old days.

If you can alter the HTML, than wrap the inputs into a form with the action set to `processEditBookSeat.php` and set also an ID like "bookSeatForm" to it so its easyer to find in js side.

Then modify the script like so:

```
  $(".confirm").easyedit();
  $("#alert").click(function() {
       $("#bookSeatForm").submit()
   });
```

Further if this method suits you why not use the default form behaviour and change the #alert element to a submit input ? That is up to you.